# I have a code that is supposed to replace a random spot in a string with an O

Tags: python, if-statement, global-variables

```
def getCSpot():
    global board
    global cspot
    spotchosen = False
    while spotchosen == False:
        spotchosen = False
        cspot = random.randint(0, 8)
        if board[cspot] == 'X' or board[cspot] == 'O':
            cspot = random.randint(0, 8)            
        else:
            spotchosen = True
            board[cspot] = 'O'
```

I dont really understand why this isn't working. It does not put the O in the string at all. I have another part of the code that determines if there is a winner when there are 3 O's or X's in a row and that doesn't work either, here is that code. Any help is much appreciated.

```
def didwin(player):
    global gameOver
    if (board[0] == player and board[1] == player and board[2] == player or
            board[3] == player and board[4] == player and board[5] == player or
            board[6] == player and board[7] == player and board[8] == player or 
            board[0] == player and board[3] == player and board[6] == player or
            board[1] == player and board[4] == player and board[7] == player or
            board[2] == player and board[5] == player and board[8] == player or 
            board[0] == player and board[4] == player and board[8] == player or
            board[2] == player and board[4] == player and board[6] == player):
        gameOver = True
        if player == 'X':
            print 'congratulations! You won!!'
            endGame()
        else:
            print 'Better luck next time, you lost!'
            endGame()
```

And for reference purposes, here is the endGame function.

```
def endGame():
    global board
    displayBoard()
    answer = ' '
    while answer == ' ':
        print 'Would you like to play another game?'
        answer = raw_input('Y/N')
    if answer == 'Y' or answer == 'y' or answer == 'Yes' or answer == 'yes':
        board = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
        game1()
        game()
    elif answer == 'N' or answer == 'n' or answer == 'No' or answer == 'no':
        exit()
```

Edit: the following is my whole code with no edits from beginning to end.

```
board = [0, 1, 2,
           3, 4, 5,
           6, 7, 8]
import random

def displayBoard():
    global board
    print board[0], '|', board[1], '|', board[2]
    print '----------'
    print board[3], '|', board[4], '|', board[5]
    print '----------'
    print board[6], '|', board[7], '|', board[8]
def getspot():
    global board
    spotchosen = False
    while spotchosen == False:
        spotchosen = False
        playerSpot = int(raw_input('Where would you like to go? '))
        if board[playerSpot] != 'X':
            board[playerSpot] = 'X'
        if board[playerSpot] != 'O':
            board[playerSpot] = 'X'
        if playerSpot == 'X':
            playerSpot = raw_input('You have already chosen that spot. Please choose another. ')
        if playerSpot == 'O':
            playerSpot = raw_input('The computer chose that spot already. Please choose another. ')
        else:
            spotchosen = True
def getCSpot():
    global board
    global cspot
    spotchosen = False
    while spotchosen == False:
        spotchosen = False
        cspot = random.randint(0, 8)
        if board[cspot] == 'X' or board[cspot] == 'O':
            cspot = random.randint(0, 8)            
        else:
            spotchosen = True
            board[cspot] = 'O'
def endGame():
    global board
    displayBoard()
    answer = ' '
    while answer == ' ':
        print 'Would you like to play another game?'
        answer = raw_input('Y/N')
    if answer == 'Y' or answer == 'y' or answer == 'Yes' or answer == 'yes':
        board = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
        game1()
        game()
    elif answer == 'N' or answer == 'n' or answer == 'No' or answer == 'no':
        exit()
def didwin(player):
    global gameOver
    if (board[0] == player and board[1] == player and board[2] == player or
            board[3] == player and board[4] == player and board[5] == player or
            board[6] == player and board[7] == player and board[8] == player or 
            board[0] == player and board[3] == player and board[6] == player or
            board[1] == player and board[4] == player and board[7] == player or
            board[2] == player and board[5] == player and board[8] == player or 
            board[0] == player and board[4] == player and board[8] == player or
            board[2] == player and board[4] == player and board[6] == player):
        gameOver = True
        if player == 'X':
            print 'congratulations! You won!!'
            endGame()
        else:
            print 'Better luck next time, you lost!'
            endGame()

    else:
        gameOver = False

def mainGame():
    gameOver = False
    while gameOver == False:
        displayBoard()
        getspot()
        didwin('X')
        didwin('O')
mainGame()
```

Comment: How is `board` defined? (PS, why are you using global variables?)

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "not working"? I created a global `board = [' ' for i in range(9)]`, pasted in and ran your `getCSpot` function, and the result is `[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'O', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']`. Which seems to me like it worked. In fact, if I call it 9 times in a row, it successfully finds an empty space and replaces it with an 'O', ultimately resulting in a list of 9 'O's. (Of course if I call it a 10th time, it loops forever.) And then `didWin('O')` prints out `Better luck next time, you lost!`.

Comment: You defined a `getCSpot()`, but you're calling a `getspot()`. If you're doing this in the interactive interpreter, rather than a script file, maybe `getspot` is an old function you defined earlier in the session, which doesn't work?

Comment: For future reference, always post a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org). If your whole program is too long to post, don't just paste fragments; strip out all the irrelevant parts as far as you can, while still leaving something that runs and exhibits the problem you want help with, and paste that.

Comment: Alright it is still not working as intended, I fixed some of the code but I was wondering if there is a problem with the way I say that the spot they want is already full because that doesnt work currently. http://pastebin.com/KPEknEd3

Comment: I explained what's wrong with your `getspot` code in my answer.

Comment: Ahh I see, I didn't notice at first that you edited it after I posted the full code, but it sadly still will not run, after entering in the code you provided and making some tweaks such as having it actually ask the user for an input hehe, it says there is a syntax error with the if statement but there isn't anything wrong with it that I can see.. I am literally going insane... I will never be a professional programmer.... here is the link to the updated getspot function http://pastebin.com/mBhWy4bM

Comment: @user1861771: please don't vandalize your own questions.  That takes away most of the value from the work that people did to help.

Comment: @user1861771: Also, once you've posted your code to a site that has history, and licensed it under CC-BY-SA, there's really no point in trying to "un-post" it. Anyone who wants to use it against you or steal it or whatever you're worried about can't be stopped that way.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that the problem, whatever it is, is in code that you didn't show us.

I didn't test your `endGame` function, to keep things simple. But I pasted in your other code, and added the following:

```
board = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
gameOver = False
def endGame():
    print 'endGame called'
for i in range(9):
    getCSpot()
    print(board)
    didwin('O')
    if gameOver:
        print 'gameOver'
        break
```

The result was:

```
[0, 'O', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[0, 'O', 2, 3, 'O', 5, 6, 7, 8]
[0, 'O', 2, 3, 'O', 5, 'O', 7, 8]
[0, 'O', 2, 3, 'O', 5, 'O', 'O', 8]
Better luck next time, you lost!
endGame called
gameOver
```

Of course the sequence is random, so it's not exactly the same every time, but it always replaces one random number at a time with 'O' until there's a 3-in-a-row, then tells me I lost.

So, it works exactly as intended. If your code doesn't work, you're doing something else wrong. Maybe you're setting up `board` or something else wrong in the initial setup?

Adding in your `displayBoard` and `endGame` code, it works until you say 'y' to play another game, at which point it calls some functions named `game1` and `game` which don't exist, raising a `NameError`.

I also saw in your start function (from the comment that you since deleted, so this is from memory) that you were calling a function called `getspot()` in the game loop, instead of calling `getCSpot()`. If `getspot` is defined somewhere, the problem is presumably that you've got one correct function and one incorrect one. Or maybe it's not defined anywhere, and by "isn't working" and "does not put the O in the string at all" you mean "doesn't get called because the game halts with an exception before I ever get a chance"?

Now that you've posted the whole thing, there are a few obvious problems.

First, you never call `getCSpot` anywhere. That's why it doesn't do anything. Presumably you want this:

```
def mainGame():
    gameOver = False
    while gameOver == False:
        displayBoard()
        getspot()
        didwin('X')
        didwin('O')
        getCSpot()
        didwin('X')
        didwin('O')
```

Also, in `getspot`, your `if` statements are all wrong. You're going to allow the move if `board[playerSpot] != 'X'`, and also allow the move if `board[playerSpot] != 'O'`—in other words, always. And then you're going to count the player as moved unless `playerSpot == 'O'` is false—which it always is, because it's supposed to be a number.

I think you want this:

```
    if board[playerSpot] == 'X':
        playerSpot = raw_input('You have already chosen that spot. Please choose another. ')
    elif board[playerSpot] == 'O':
        playerSpot = raw_input('The computer chose that spot already. Please choose another. ')
    else:
        board[playerSpot] = 'X'
        spotchosen = True
```

Comment: If I knew how to post my code in a comment (I just cant figure it out it seems hehe) I would just post my whole code.

Comment: @user1861771: You can't post code usefully in a comment; that's not your fault. You can post it at, e.g., pastebin.com and then post a link here. Or just edit your question.

Comment: I have just edited the question to include the entirety of the code at the bottom.